# MYSQL date subtraction

Tags: mysql, date, time

I want to substract date to reach online users where have been in 10 minutes. My logic is like below. But it is not working

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE NOW() - user_last_login <=10
```

is it good approach?

I store date in format : 2013-09-05 15:30:45 -- YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Comment: +1 for storing a standard date format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySQL [TIMESTAMPDIFF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function to find it

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,NOW(),user_last_login)<=10
```

Comment: but affected column is 0. I have value for user_last_login column

Comment: also is datediff() function calculate Time?

Comment: @hakiko try timestampdiff

Comment: I think problem is about my Server Time. I check it. It comes 2 hour back

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM user 
WHERE NOW() - interval 10 minute <= user_last_login
```